# Knockout.js validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout.js tech where I Googled many site to resolve my situation where I couldn't find a better option.
How to validate a date using Knockout.js? Where in my case if the user typed the date in a wrong format say for e.g if the valid date format is dd-M-yyyy but the user is typing M-dd-yyyy it should automatically convert it to a valid date format.

My sample code is this,

```
self.dateOfBirth = ko.observable(0).extend({
            required: { message: 'Date of Birth is required', params: true },
            date: { format: 'dd-M-YYYY' ,
                message: 'Not a valid date format',params:true
           }
```

My HTML design is this,

```
    <input class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text" data-bind="value: dateOfBirth, format:'dd-M-YYYY', valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

Comment: If you allow user to type the date, he could type "9/11/2014". How would you know he mean, 11-Sep-2014 or 9-Nov-2014?

Comment: @SBirthare: yeah I thought about that scenario.. i can keep placeholder to mention the format.. I need to change if it is anyway..if it is 9/11/2014 the system should take in this format only dd-M-yyyy

Comment: I am still not sure how you will figure out when to change as date I gave is perfectly valid. Will your user like it? Leaving that part to you, I am just going to make another suggestion. I have not used KnockoutJS extensively, so its just a suggestion. Why don't you keep Knockout out of this and just use plain JS/JQuery to achieve it?

Comment: If it is javascript how will you be able to acheive this. In my case I dn't need to throw error. My main aim is to focus on the conversion of the format..

Comment: Write an appropriate event handler in JS, there you can fetch current value, apply a nice Regex and see if it fits the valid format criteria. If you want to perform a transformation (I can imagine valid one is if user enter "9/11/2014" you can update the value to "9-Nov-2014") and update the text box again. All using java script.

Comment: thank u.. will try and let you know the result.. i just need to google how to update the textbox using javascript..!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "Writable computed observables" [example 3](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html#example-3-a-value-converter) and [example 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html#example-4-filtering-and-validating-user-input) on the official Knockout documentation site.

Example:

```
this.formattedDate = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        return this.date();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        // convert date to dd-M-YYYY, then write the 
        // raw data back to the underlying "date" observable
        value = convertDate(value); // add your own conversion routine
        this.date(value); // write to underlying storage
    },
    owner: this
});
```

Also consider using the [`textInput`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding, instead of `value` combined with `valueUpdate`, for consistent cross-browser handling.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Knockout event and capture its change event and then use moment.js library to convert it into any date format you like.

In HTML:

`<input class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date of 
    Birth" type="text" data-bind="value: dateOfBirth, event: { change: dataChanged}, 
    valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">`

In javascript:
Inside your viewModel

//this function will be called when the date will be changed

`self.dataChanged = function(){
   //using moment .js here change the format to dd-M-YYYY as desired
   var validFormat = moment(self.dateOfBirth()).format('dd-M-yyyy');
   self.dateOfBirth(validFormat);
}`

for further details check moment.js liberary